# How can I draw the lines also in runtime and not only in scene as gizmos?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At the top I added :

```
public LineRenderer LineRenderer;
```

In the Start :

```
void Start()
{
  DrawTraffic();
}
```

This is the gizmos method :

```
void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        for (int k0 = 0; k0 < transform.childCount; k0++)
        {
            Vector3 Pos = transform.GetChild(k0).transform.localPosition;
            Gizmos.color = Color.green;
            Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(Pos, MaxStartScatter);
            Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.GetChild(k0).position, transform.GetChild(k0).position + transform.GetChild(k0).transform.TransformVector(Vector3.forward) * 300);
            Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
            for (int k1 = 0; k1 < 10; k1++)
            {
                Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(Pos += transform.GetChild(k0).transform.TransformVector(Vector3.forward) * 30, MaxStartScatter);
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the DrawTraffic I want to be show in the runtime :

```
private void DrawTraffic()
    {
        // set the color of the line
        LineRenderer.startColor = Color.red;
        LineRenderer.endColor = Color.red;

        // set width of the renderer
        LineRenderer.startWidth = 0.3f;
        LineRenderer.endWidth = 0.3f;

        for (int k0 = 0; k0 < transform.childCount; k0++)
        {
            Vector3 Pos = transform.GetChild(k0).transform.localPosition;

            LineRenderer.SetPosition(0, Pos);

           
        }
    }
```

but I'm not sure what to do next in the DRawTraffic method. How to draw the lines between all positions like it's in the gizmos ?

I tried this now but getting outofbound exception on line :

```
LineRenderer.SetPosition(2, transform.GetChild(k0).position + transform.GetChild(k0).transform.TransformVector(Vector3.forward) * 300);
```

This is what I tried :

```
private void DrawTraffic()
    {
        // set the color of the line
        LineRenderer.startColor = Color.red;
        LineRenderer.endColor = Color.red;

        // set width of the renderer
        LineRenderer.startWidth = 0.3f;
        LineRenderer.endWidth = 0.3f;

        for (int k0 = 0; k0 < transform.childCount; k0++)
        {
            Vector3 Pos = transform.GetChild(k0).transform.localPosition;

            LineRenderer.SetPosition(0, Pos);
            LineRenderer.SetPosition(1, transform.GetChild(k0).position);
            LineRenderer.SetPosition(2, transform.GetChild(k0).position + transform.GetChild(k0).transform.TransformVector(Vector3.forward) * 300);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the value of `LineRenderer.positionCount` to `transform.childCount`
(or whichever number of points you want to draw) before calling `LineRenderer.SetPosition`, that's most likely why you're getting the out-of-bounds exception.

There's an example in the reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-positionCount.html

Comment: Now there is no errors/exceptions but it's drawing only one line and not like the gizmos. What have I missed ?

Comment: "not like the gizmos" : Do you mean, the sphere are missing? Or is there something else? For the spheres, unfortunately, for non-debug purposes, if you want spheres to be rendered, I think you'll have to instantiate a prefab that looks how you want, and destroy it when you stop displaying the traffic.

Comment: I found how to do it. THanks.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi Feel free to share the solution here for other people that would want to do the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Working solution. This is just to show to how to work with the linerenderer to draw lines between multiple positions.

```
private void DrawTraffic()
    {
        // set the color of the line
        lineRenderer.startColor = Color.red;
        lineRenderer.endColor = Color.red;

        // set width of the renderer
        lineRenderer.startWidth = 0.3f;
        lineRenderer.endWidth = 0.3f;

        lineRenderer.positionCount = transform.childCount;

        var spawns = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Spawn");
        var vP = new Vector3[spawns.Length];
        var seg = spawns.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < spawns.Length; i++)
        {
            vP[i] = spawns[i].transform.position;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < seg; i++)
        {
            float t = i / (float)seg;
            lineRenderer.positionCount = seg;
            lineRenderer.SetPositions(vP);
        }
    }
```